# How to use the \appto across the environments?

Tags: environments, etoolbox

In the following code:

```
\newtheorem{myans}{Answer}
\def\myword{Word: }
\newcommand{\addword}{first, }
\begin{myans}
... \appto{\myword}{\addword} ...
\end{myans}
\renewcommand{\addword}{second, }
\begin{myans}
... \appto{\myword}{\addword} ...
\end{myans}
\myword
```

I think that the final \myword should be "Word: first, second, ". But the actual result is just "Word: ".

It seems like that the command \addword can only be useful in an environment, and at the end of the environment, the \addword will refrest the word?

How to use this command across the environments?

Comment: Welcome! An environment creates a group. You will need `\gappto` (g = global) or rather `\xappto` (x = global and full expansion) because you only add `\addword` to your `\myword`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel \xappto could be dangerous if the argument contains real text with arbitrary commands.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel It works! Thanks!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree which is where `\xappto{\myword}{\expandonce{\addword}}` might come in handy.

Answer (score 4):

Every environment creates a group, meaning all actions are forgotten after the `\end` – unless they are instructed to be global. For this, `etoolbox` also provides `\gappto` (`g`lobal).

However, if you use this, your last line would expand to

```
Word: second, second
```

since you've only added `\addword` to your `\myword` and not its content, for this you can use a combination of `\xappto` (`x` = global *and* full expansion) and `\expandonce` to protect possible fragile commands in your `\addword`.

This will highly depend on what your `\addword` could possibly contain, maybe `\protected@xappto` would be more suited.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\newtheorem{myans}{Answer}
\def\myword{Word: }
\newcommand{\addword}{first, }
\begin{myans}
... \xappto{\myword}{\expandonce\addword} ...
\end{myans}
\renewcommand{\addword}{second, }
\begin{myans}
... \xappto{\myword}{\expandonce\addword} ...
\end{myans}
\myword
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: The `l3tl` package of the LaTeX3 bundle offers `\tl_gput_right:No \myword {\addword}` as a combination of `\xappto` and `\expandonce`.